# Como receber mensagens do firebase console no android em segundo plano?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

Tenho um app que envia as notificações do firebase console e minhas notificações não chega no celular quando estão em segundo plano mas quando estão no primeiro plano com o app aberto a notificação chega normalmente. Gostaria do apoio de vocês para solucionar meu problema.

```
package br.com.guiacistore

import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.media.RingtoneManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage

/**
 * Created by faro on 9/7/17.
 */

class NotificationFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
        if (remoteMessage?.notification != null) {
          sendNotifications(remoteMessage?.notification?.body, remoteMessage.data)
        }

    //        if (remoteMessage?.notification != null) {
    //            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    //        }

    }


    private fun sendNotifications(mensagem: String?, dados: Map<String, String>) {


        val intent = Intent(this, StorageActivity::class.java)
        val bundle = Bundle()

        for (key in dados.keys) {
          val valor = dados[key].toString()
          bundle.putString(key, valor)

        }


        intent.putExtras(bundle)

        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        val pendingIntent = getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        val uriSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationCompatBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)


        notificationCompatBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.guiaci)
        notificationCompatBuilder.setContentTitle("Guiaci")
        notificationCompatBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.guiaci))

        notificationCompatBuilder.setContentText(mensagem)
        notificationCompatBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
        notificationCompatBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        notificationCompatBuilder.setSound(uriSound)

        notificationCompatBuilder.priority = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationCompatBuilder.build())

    }

}
```

Comment: Quais dados você está colocando no console? Por padrão, quando se envia uma mensagem pelo console, caso o app esteja em **background** o Firebase exibe automaticamente as notificações, portanto não seria necessário implementar o método `onMessageReceived()`. Esse método só é necessário para tratar as mensagens quando seu app está em **foreground**

Comment: Coloquei título e mensagem, basicamente!